# Setting Event to all controls inside a form in VB

Tags: vb.net, events

I want to set an event to every single button/picturebox in my project (this include all forms).
The goal is to provide the button an animation as the user rests the cursor on the control.

I know how to do it by:

```
Private Sub bItem_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     Picturebox.Size = Picturebox.Size + 5
End Sub
```

Is there a loop I can create to apply it to every control in my project? Or will I have to insert this line into all controls?

Tks for you help

Comment: Loop through the controls and addhandler to a method that does the animation... or another option create a usercontrol and inherit the picturebox/button and put your code in it. Then use it anywhere you want and then you dont have to mess with adding and removing handlers.

Comment: Do you mean something like this :

`For Each cnt As Control In Me.Controls

            ' Do your stuff here.

   Next`